# Remove thirdparty loggers from my main program

Tags: java, log4j

I have the following program. When I run it, I am getting lots of debug logs in my console. I don't want this logs. How can I remove them from console.
[main] DEBUG com.couchbase.client.core.config.refresher.CarrierRefresher - Starting polling with interval 2500ms

```
public class CouchbaseTests {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME).setLevel(Level.INFO);
        Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create("127.0.0.1");
        cluster.authenticate("Administrator","12345678");
        Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("BUCKET_NAME");
}
}
```

Comment: Change that LogLevel to ERROR

Comment: I did change the Log Level but still I see Debug logs. Log Level order: TRACE
DEBUG
INFO
WARN
ERROR
FATAL.
If I set log level to INFO we should not get debug level logs.

Comment: Can you add what logs you are seeing?